# Python3 Compile Error

Tags: python-3.x

Error message:

```
FE..
************ MISSING LINE ***************
file 1 line number: 2
missing line in file 2, no match for file 1 line:
'=================== ROUND 1 ===================\n'
*****************************************

F..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_combat_round (__main__.TestRPG)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_rpg.py", line 64, in test_combat_round
    self.assertIsNone(combat_round(self.rich, self.thompson))
  File "/Users/ajsmitty12/Desktop/ISTA130/rpg.py", line 124, in combat_round
    player1.attack(player1, player2)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'attack'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_attack (__main__.TestRPG)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_rpg.py", line 42, in test_attack
    self.assertEqual(out, buf.getvalue())
AssertionError: 'Rich attacks Thompson!\n\tHits for 5 hit points!\n\tThompson         h[24 chars]g.\n' != 'Rich attacks Thompson (HP: 10)!\n\tHits for 5 hit     points!\n\tT[33 chars]g.\n'
- Rich attacks Thompson!
+ Rich attacks Thompson (HP: 10)!
?                      +++++++++
    Hits for 5 hit points!
    Thompson has 5 hit points remaining.


======================================================================
FAIL: test_main (__main__.TestRPG)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_rpg.py", line 117, in test_main
    self.assertTrue(compare_files('rpg_main_out_correct.txt', out))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=1)
Correctness score =  57.14285714285714%



    Description:
    -This program will simulate combate for a simple Role Playing Game (RPG).
    - The game has a single type of character, the Fighter.
    -Each inidividual Fighter has an integer value caled "hit points" that represents his/her current health (the amount of damage he/she can sustain before death)
    -It will simulate combat between 2 Fighers. 
    -Combat is divided into rounds:
    -During each round each combatant will make 1 attempt to stike the other. 
    -We will use random numbers to simulate rolling dice, the higher number attacks first, and the lower number goes 2nd if still alive. 
    -If there is a tie, the players will go at the same time, they will attack eachother at the same moment. 
    -During a simultaneous attack both Fighters will get to attack even if one (or both) if (are) killed during that round. 
    -The progam will use a random number to determine whether an attack attempt is successful or not. 
    -Each successful attack will inflict damage on the opponent. 
    -To simulate damage, we'll reduce the opponent's hit points by another random number
    -When a Fighters hit points are reduced to 0 (or less than 0) that player is considered to be dead. 
    -Combat round continue until one(or both) combatants are dead. 
    '''
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to call my instances for Fighter that I created within the class too my combat function, that is outside of the class.
I am also wondering if I am comparing player1 and player2's random numbers correctly. When messing around with it I tried using:
    player1 = Fighter()
    player2 = Fighter()
When doing this my error message would said that Fighter() > Fighter() are not comparable. 
Lastly, not quite sure why my test_attack is failing.

My code (so far):

```
import random
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self, name):
      '''
     -This is my initializer method, which takes 2 parameters: 
            -Self
            -Name (a string, the name of a fighter)
        -This method will set a name attribute to the value of the name parameter
        -It will also set a hit_points attribute to 10 (all fighters begin life with 10 hit points).
        '''
        self.name = name
        self.hit_points = 10

    def __repr__(self):
        '''
        -This method takes 1 parameter, self. 
        -It returns a string showing the name and hit points of the instances in the following format:
                Bonzo (HP:  9)
        '''
        result = str(self.name) + " (HP: " + str(self.hit_points) + ")"
        return result

    def take_damage(self, damage_amount):
        '''
        -This method takes 2 parameters:
            -self (the Fighter instance that calls the method)
            -damage_amount (an integer representing the number of hit points of damage that have just been inflicted on this Fighter):
                -The method should first decrease the hit_points attribute by the damage_amount.
                -Next, it should check to see if the Fighter has died from the damage:
                    -A hit_points value that is 0 or less indicates death, and will print a message like the following:
                        \tAlas, Bonzo has fallen!
                    -Otherwise, it will print a message like the following (in this example, the player had 5 hit points left over after damage)
                        \tBonzo has 5 hit points remaining. 
                -The method returns nothing.

        ''' 
        self.hit_points = self.hit_points - damage_amount
        if self.hit_points <= 0:
            print('\t' + 'Alas, ' + str(self.name) + ' has fallen!')
        else:
            print('\t' + str(self.name) + ' has ' + str(self.hit_points) + ' hit points remaining.')
    def attack(self, other):
        '''
        -This method takes 2 parameters:
            -self 
            -other (another Fighter instance being attacked by self)
        -The method will print the name of the attacker and attacked in the following format:
            Bonzo attacks Chubs!
        -Next, determine whether the attack hits by generating a random integer between 1 and 20
            -Use the randrange function from the random module to get this number.
            -A number that is 12 or higher indicates a hit:
                - For an attack that hits, generate a random number between 1 and 6(using random.randrange) to represent the amount of damage inflicted by the attack 
                    ***Do NOT use the from random import randrange sytanze (randrange works like range, not like randint (think about the upper bounds you choose)).
                - Print the amount of damage inflicted like the following:
                    \tHits for 4 hit points!
                -Invoke the take_damage method on the victim (i.e. on other), passing it the amount of damage inflicted. 
            -For an attack that misses, print the following message:
                \tMisses!
        -This method returns nothing. 
        '''
        self.other = Fighter(self.name)
        print(str(self.name) + ' attacks ' + str(other) + '!')
        attack = random.randrange(1, 20)
        if attack >= 12:
            damage_amount = random.randrange(1, 6)
            print('\t' + 'Hits for ' + str(damage_amount) + ' hit points!')
            other.take_damage(damage_amount)
        else:
            print('\t' + 'Misses!')

    def is_alive(self):
        '''
        -This method takes 1 parameter, self. 
            -It returns True if self has a positive number of points, False otherwise.
        '''

        if self.hit_points > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
def combat_round(player1, player2):
    '''
    -This function takes 2 parameters:
        -The 1st is an instance of Fighter. 
        -The 2nd is another instance of Fighter. 
    -It determines which of the 2 fighters attacks 1st for the round by generating a random interger (use randrange) between 1 and 6 for each fighter:
        -if the numbers are equal:
            -print the following message:
                Simultaneous!
            -Have each figher instance call his attack method on the other figher (the 1st figher in the argument list must attack first to make the test work correctly)
        -if one number is larger:
            -the fighter with the larger roll attacks 1st (by calling his attack method and passing it the figher being attacked).
            -if the 2nd fighter survives the attack (call is_alive), he then   attack the 1st. 
    -This function returns nothing.
    '''
    Fighter.name = player1
    Fighter.name = player2
    player1 = random.randrange(1, 6)
    player2 = random.randrange(1, 6)
    if player1 == player2:
        print('Simultaneous!')
        player1.attack(player2)
    if player1 > player2:
        player1.attack(player2)
        if player2.is_alive() == True:
            player2.attack(player1)
    if player2 > player1:
        player2.attack(player1)
        if player1.is_alive() == True:
            player1.attack(player2)
```

Comment: Kindly edit your question nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You class looks okay, but the `combat_round` function has some problems.

You were on the right track with `player1 = Fighter()` etc..

```
player1 = Fighter(name = 'Jeff')
player2 = Fighter(name = 'Bill')
```

But now you want to choose one to go first. You cant just compare them with  >, <, == without customizing special methods like `__eq__()` because Python doesn't know which attribute to compare. How about setting an attribute then comparing it:

```
player1.speed = random.randrange(1,6)
player2.speed = random.randrange(1,6)
```

Now you can write tests like this:

```
if player1.speed == player2.speed:
    print("Simultaneous!")
```

Also, if the function `combat_round()` takes *instances* of fighter, then you dont need to instantiate them inside the function. But, if the function takes strings that are the names of the fighters then you would do it like my example.